# Why should HR post the job ad. again on social media before conducting the interview(s)?

Tags: interviewing, human-resources, germany, job-description, social-media

I've been invited for a phone interview scheduled for a few days from now (Germany), but I noticed the job advertisement was uploaded again on the social media yesterday (Xing, Linkedin).

Is this a typical act expecting from the HR especially for big companies to keep posting the ads. again and again every 2 weeks? or it means they do not really rely on the candidates they have invited for the interview?

Comment: Believe it or not, they are not going to stop looking for candidates just because they managed to organise an interview with you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They probably have a closing date for all applications and are just "refreshing" the advert to catch as many as possible.

The outcome of the interview may not be told to you at the end of the interview - you may be the 75th candidate interviewed so far...

So, expect to be contacted at some time after the final close date when they have made their final deliberations.

Answer (score 4):

There are several reasons that can be summed up as follows: The candidate pool is not large enough or skilled enough or a combination of both that they feel confident there will be enough people to hire.

This might be because there are only a few candidates. The job market for anything software related is so sucked dry in Germany right now, that for some ads you can be happy having *a* candidate at all.

It might be because they look for a specific skillset and all the candidates come close, but not really hit it.

It might be because they have multiple positions to fill, although it's only one ad because all the positions are basically the same.

Answer (score 1):

Posting job ads on social media comes with quite a high fee, often for a fixed time. If the time the ad stays online is over, the company can either pay again so the ad stays online the whole time or they let the ad expire and start a new term with a new upload of the same ad. The second option brings more value to the company, because a new upload pushes the ad to users of the network (e.g. in a newsletter). This is probably the reason the ad was uploaded again when the hiring process was not yet completed sucessfully.