# Do I have the right to request more information about a scheduled interview?

Tags: interviewing, communication, human-resources, germany, process

I'm going to have an interview a few days from now (phone-based), but I have not given the information about the interview structure which I was supposed to receive via email. I called back the number who had contacted me but I reached a voicemail and my voice message has not been replied yet.

Generally, I'd like to know if it is a technical interview or an HR Q&A session and the job title of the people who will be interviewing me. But, I'm not sure if it is assumed common if an applicant calls the company asking for the HR department to investigate such information? or they'd be annoyed and this might reflect badly on their impression about me?

Comment: "an applicant calls the company asking for the HR department" - it might be a bit awkward if you try to do it this way, as whomever you end up talking to may not have this information readily available, or even necessarily have access to it. You might want to try the number you have again, or ask specifically for the person you were in contact with, or wait a bit longer for a reply.

Comment: If this is Germany, as you mention in your other post, then they may not reply as it is the weekend and they could well send you a reply Monday or Tuesday. Have some patience.  https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/136439/75821

Comment: @SolarMike Yes, this is Germany, but I called the guy on Friday! :D
I'll do it again on Monday! ;)

Comment: Keep in mind that there is a difference between "having a right" to information vs "obtaining it in a manner that won't reflect poorly on me." Your question seems to bunch these together. As a hiring manager, I wouldn't mind if someone wanted to know some details about the interview structure, but if the candidate called several times before I'd even had a chance to listen to their first voicemail, and spent a lot of time asking specific, detailed questions about the interview, I'd be turned off very fast under the impression that they were high-maintenance and inflexible.

Comment: @dwizum: Yes, I understand your point and will keep that in mind! ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you are right and you have every right to be made aware of the nature of the interview you're going to face. That's how you can be better prepared for the interview.

While they may deny to inform you the *exact* job title of the interviewer(s), but the have to at least let you know regarding the nature of the interview.

Usually, I'd say it's common for organizations to detail the interview process structure (how many rounds and their nature - telephonice, skype/webex, in-person, and/or verbal, written etc.) to the interviewee before the process begins - however in case they did not do that themselves, go ahead and ask them for that information.

If you're not getting a response over phone, try leaving them a message and if you're got an email you can contact to, send them an e-mail asking about the details of the interview process.